# Dependency Inversion Principle: is a low level module allowed to have a hidden reference to another low level module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, dependency-inversion, solid

Consider the following code from Web Dev Simplified's video on the Dependency Inversion Principe:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9oHY5TllWaU

```
class Store {
  constructor(paymentProcessor) {
    this.paymentProcessor = paymentProcessor;
  }

  purchase(quantity) {
    this.paymentProcessor.pay(200 * quantity);
  }

}

class StripePaymentProcessor {
  constructor(user) {
    this.user = user;
    this.stripe = new Stripe(user);
  }
  pay(amountInDollars) {
    this.stripe.makePayment(amountInDollars * 100);
  }
}

class Stripe {
  constructor(user) {
    this.user = user;
  }

  makePayment(amountInCents) {
    console.log(
      `${this.user} made a payment of $${amountInCents / 100} with Stripe`
    );
  }
}

class PayPalPaymentProcessor {
  constructor(user) {
    this.user = user;
    this.paypal = new PayPal();
  }
  pay(amountInDollars) {
    this.paypal.makePayment(this.user, amountInDollars);
  }
}

class PayPal {
  makePayment(user, amountInDollars) {
    console.log(`${user} made a payment of $${amountInDollars} with PayPal`);
  }
}

// const store = new Store(new StripePaymentProcessor('John'));
const store = new Store(new PayPalPaymentProcessor('John'));
store.purchase(2);
```

This should be an example of successful implementation of the dependency inversion principle, as we are loosely coupling the high level module `Store` & the low level modules `Stripe` & `Paypal`.

What bothers me, however, is that we are creating new instances of `Stripe` & `Paypal` in both `StripePaymentProcessor` & `PayPalPaymentProcessor`.

Since we are instantiating another class inside those classes, without injecting it via the parameters, are we not creating a hidden dependency & therefore violating the D in SOLID ? Are we not just moving the dependency to another class?

If this is no violation, are we then allowed to instantiate a different low level module inside a low level module?

Would including each payment processor in Typescript as a parameter to `Store` which uses a `PaymentProcessor` interface solve the dependency issue by applying an abstraction?

This has been making me mad & I'd appreciate some clarification. Thank you.

Comment: I have written my humble opinion about this kind of thing here: https://kunststube.net/static. May be of interest.

Comment: @deceze I appreciate your reply & will check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look from this perspective, `Store` is your domain code and it needs to execute payment code. Now most often, for payment processing, we depend upon external code (3rd party libraries). We can change our code but we cannot change 3rd party code and that is where we create boundaries. That is why you created Dependency inversion there.

The `StripePaymentProcessor` and `PaypalPaymentProcessor` are your anti-corruption/gateway/adapter classes and they have only 1 responsibility to adapt the external code to fulfill your domain requirements. That is why they are expected to have dependency over the thing they are adapting.

We created DI to contain the ripple effect in case if external code's API changes and in this case it is contained within both `PaymentProcessor` classes. Even if the API of any external code changes we only have to update the respective `PaymentProcessor` to adapt to the new change.

You can check an example of DI [here](https://harshmatharu.com/blog/solid-principles-in-csharp).

Comment: I really appreciate your reply. It's been eye-opening for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Stripe and PayPal are neither considered to be dependencies nor low-level modules.

These two constructs represent a data model, or domain model, or simply entities with information to be persisted into a storage or to be retrieved to client.

For this reason, they should have no lifetime aspects. By definition they are created (or queried from a storage) at specific points, as part of the flow.

The author of the store example (as presented by you) chose to instantiate a single instance for a Stripe (or PayPal) inside the processor object's constructor probably for simplification, but still it can be considered valid in some scenarios.

Comment: Thank you, your answer really helps me contextualize the code. I wonder, would you have refactored this code differently?

Comment: It really depends on the purpose of processor objects from the business perspective, what we have here is just a simplified example.